# Network File Sharing Mechanisms in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, samba, shared-folders

I have noticed Ubuntu has several mechanisms to share folders with other machines on a network:

1. For example, if I am in `Nautilus` (the file manager), I can right click on a folder, go to `Properties`, and then go to the tab `Share` and activate `Share this folder`.
2. I can also install `samba`, edit the file `/etc/samba/smb.conf` to enable access to a specific folder and start the service.

I noticed that if I use both approaches **simultaneously**  to enable access to the same folder, I can actually see two links to the same folder on Explorer when I access my machine through a network path from Windows.

My questions are:

1. What is the first mechanism based on? (is it running another instance of samba behind the scenes? If so, where is the `smb.conf` file for it?
2. Why the redundancy?
3. Are there any other mechanisms to share folders?

For reference, this is all on Ubuntu 12.04, from a virtual machine (Virtual Box) from within Windows 7 64.

Answer (score 3):

Both mechanisms are based on Samba. The first time you share a folder from Nautilus, it prompts you to install Samba. The configuration is managed by Nautilus ; you don't need root access (except to install Samba).

Other ways of sharing files...

- SFTP : install openssh and you get secure FTP which will work with clients like Filezilla (GUI) or plain old `scp`
- VirtualBox : The guest extensions include a mechanism for mounting folders from your host - create shared folders and mount them as instructed in the manual
- NFS : The Linux network file system
- RDP sharing : The rdesktop utility can provide access to client folders on the server using the -disk option
- FTP : the bog standard
- And more...

Of these? I use RDP shares, VirtualBox shares, SFTP, and I mount CIFS / SMB shares on Linux.