# how to map an Ubuntu share on another Ubuntu machine?

Tags: networking, shared-folders

I've found questions on mapping a Windows share in Ubuntu, and an Ubuntu Server share on Windows, and Samba, and NTFS, and VirtualBox -- but I can't find how to map an Ubuntu share on another Ubuntu machine...!

- I'm running 2 PC's at home, both plain-vanilla Ubuntu 14.04.
- On both, some folders have been shared using Nautilus, right-clicking on a folder and choosing "Local network share".
- In Nautilus, I can "browse network" and see the shared folders, but when I show the address (Ctrl+L) then it's like "smb://other-desktop/public/". My apps (specifically Beyond Compare 3) won't read that path.

**How do I map a remote folder to my local filesystem tree??**

Update: [This post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162464/network-file-sharing-mechanisms-in-ubuntu?rq=1) lists many ways to share. Surely, one among them is more recommended for normal users? I'm not looking for "datacenter-scale" solutions -- just something simple that I can explain to my wife :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're find a directory in your /var/run/usr area that you can link to something more readible.

For instance:

```
/var/run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share\:server\=hera5\,share\=olympia/
```

Browse the /var/run/user and find the exact patch such as above.  Make a folder that you can easily access and link it to that.

```
$ mkdir ~/myshare
$ ln -s /var/run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share\:server\=hera5\,share\=olympia/ ~/myshare
```

Now you can access the folder with "ls ~/myshare"

By the way, you don't have to be super user to do this.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that "`/var/run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share\:server\=hera5\,share\=olympia/`" is a valid path in the file system?

Comment: Yes.  It's a valid path.  I link it to "~/myhera5" for convenience.  If you follow the steps I provided for you, you'll actually see this first hand.  Would you mind showing us what you find in your /var/run/[userid]/gvfs folder for the folder that you'll be conveniently linking for your wife?

Comment: there is no folder with my userid, nor literally "userid", in my /var/run/... there are samba/ and user/ dirs but they seem unrelated. I am confused!

Comment: thanks, this gave me a valid path, but read-only. How do I make it writable?

Comment: You should have the same permissions in this folder that you have when you found it in Nautilus' network browser.  Are you saying the permissions are different?  The permissions are defined when setting up the samba share.  See your network administrator and ask them to give you (your login user) write access to the share.

Comment: @ldjames - this is about my home computers, not at work, so there is no administrator. Why Samba, I thought that was only used for Windows? I'm exasperated that Linux file sharing on a home LAN is so difficult.

Comment: It appears, while you're may not be the best, you may be the administrator that setup the samba.  I'm refering to samba because you referenced an "//smb" in your question.  I (the computer administrator at my home) tested the steps I gave you under samba which works.  So who ever setup the samba, you'll have to ask them to give your userid write access.  If you're not using samba, you might have to specify the type of sharing you're using to get guidance on providing write access to the resource.

Comment: Yes I set up the shares by right-clicking on the folders I wanted to share. I made sure to select the two checkboxes about write access and "allow guests". So I think I did all I can to share it "wide-open" but I still can't write to it from another machine. Do I need to set up some kind of domain server, group management, or network administration central? I just have 2 regular pc's on a home LAN, no server or anything.